# How to find location for stretch of values more than fixed number and their average in dataframe python3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data-frame something like this:

[image]

And I wish to find the the location (start and end) and the average of the stretch of stretch where values in column 2 are more than 0.2. Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `pandas` this could be done as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "value": [0.28, 0.26, 0.22, 0.14, 0.16, 0.14, 0.10, 0.18, 0.30, 0.32, 0.30, 0.24, 0.08, 0.08, 0.10]
})

(
    df
    # check if values are sequential and above/below the treshold
    .assign(range = lambda x: (x["value"] < 0.20).cumsum())
    # drop the extra rows below with values below the treshold
    .loc[lambda x: x["value"] > 0.20]
    .reset_index()
    # group by the sequence number and aggregate
    .groupby("range")
    .agg({"index": ["min", "max"], "value": "mean"})
    # reset index and drop extra column
    .reset_index()
    .drop("range", axis=1)
)
```

Which gives the following dataframe as output:

```
#   index         value
#     min max      mean
# 0     0   2  0.253333
# 1     8  11  0.290000
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works like magic. I was tempted to do it using data frame. That's why posted here.